BSTR Differences between SysAllocString() and BSTR()?
I'm writing a program that takes input from the command-line and uses that input to connect to a remote WMI server and execute methods. My code is as follows:
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <comdef.h>
#include <WbemIdl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    // <SNIP>

    /* Build dynamic string containing the hostname of the target and namespace.
       Example: \\DSKT-390047\ROOT\CIMV2 */
    wchar_t cimv2[256] = { 0 };
    swprintf_s(cimv2, 256, L"\\\\%ls\\ROOT\\CIMV2", argv[1]);

    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;
    hr = pLoc->ConnectServer(BSTR(cimv2), BSTR(argv[2]), BSTR(argv[3]), NULL,
    0, NULL, NULL, &pSvc);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // <SNIP>
}

The ConnectServer() method requires 8 arguments, 5 of which are of type BSTR. Microsoft details that to create BSTR types I must do so like the following:
BSTR MyBstr = SysAllocString(L"foo");

However, I've seen some developers use BSTR(variable) too, where the variable is of type wchar_t*, so I'm wondering what are the differences between both? I cannot find much on the latter.
Am I okay doing so as I am now? Or should I allocate BSTR types first, use them, then free them?
I'm thinking that the way I'm doing now avoids the fact of having to free these allocated objects, but something is not right.

Side note : Your code as it is has memory leaks all over! Use ATL::CComBSTR it will manage the memory managment of BSTR's correctly for you.  Same with COM pointers, use ATL::CComPtr. If you can use C++20, use std::format for your string formatting (avoid the old "C" style printf functions).

See documentation on ATL::CComBSTR

Pretty much everything is in official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr, so, no your code is not okay.

(BSTR) cast of a wchar_t* type is a serious programming error which, while it will compile and may work, will result in failures when a function that would take a BSTR tries to operate on it because the BSTR type has the size carried before the pointer and therefore, may contain null characters. Read more here.  It was created that way to be compatible with wchar_t* where wchar_t* is needed, i.e. you can pass a BSTR to a function that expects a wchar_t*. But not the other way around.
BSTR is actually this structure:
struct BSTR
{
     unsigned int sz = <the_size>;
     wchar_t str[the_size];
     wchar_t nullchar = 0;
};

where you actually get a pointer to str, not to the start of the structure, to make it compatible with wchar_t* so the cast to wchar_t* will work in functions like wcslen if the BSTR doesn't contain null characters. This might effectively prevent the programmer from detecting their errors.
Just try, for example, to use SysStringLen on a wchar_t*. Functions that operate on BSTRs will subtract 4 from the passed value and expect a size to be there.
The proper way is to use _bstr_t to wrap, which will internally create SysAllocString on construction and SysFreeString on destruction.
_bstr_t f(L"Hello");
// pass f to a function that expects a BSTR.


Thanks. Could I pass argv[n] where argv is of type wchar_t to SysAllocString? It seems OLECHAR is a typedef for wchar so I assume this would be the correct way? I would then free the allocated objects once done?

Yes, SysAllocString will convert a wchar_t* to a BSTR. However, to avoid the use of SysFreeString later (when you have used SysAllocString), it's better to use _bstr_t which does automatic destruction and reference counting, much like CComPtr<> or std::shared_ptr.

Brilliant. So for something like defining a hostname I could do _bstr_t hostname(argv[n]) and then pass hostname where a function requires a BSTR type?

Exactly that. It's a C++ style wrapper which will do the work for you.

Thank you. Lots of more new stuff to learn coming of C to C++! Have a great rest of your weekend.

No BSTR is NOT a simple cast of wchar_t*, BSTR also needs a com memory allocator, ::AllocSysString.  And no do NOT use the #import generated _bstr_t (or any other smart types). Use ATL's wrapper classes.  (over  20 years of COM experience here)

"SysAllocString will convert a wchar_t to a BSTR."* - That's not a conversion. It's an allocation and a copy. @PepijnKramer _bstr_t is a regular C++ class defined in a regular C++ header file. It is older than ATL's wrappers and has better compiler support. Why are you ever so loudly voicing your unfounded opinion on a topic (Windows programming) that you clearly lack experience with? You know just barely enough to give dangerous advice. Best not to.

@IInspectable Well I have 20+ years of experience in COM and windows programming . SysAllocString is needed to allocate BSTR s when you have out of proc communication (you cannot use std::wstring at all). _bstr_t is "usable" but has its quirks (and yes I cannot remember the exact details, because I changed to CComBSTR the moment it was released).

_bstr_t wrapper types are generated from #import, but I recommend using #import with "raw interfaces only" and use ATL that's all

@PepijnKramer The "quirk" you're thinking of is not a property of any given BSTR management wrapper. It's rather the fact that authors have design choices, and most BSTR wrappers disagree on the behavior when re-seating an object that already owns a BSTR. Kinda odd that you're very vocal in rejecting a particular implementation but then do not even know why.

@PepijnKramer I also have over 25 years of Windows+COM experience, and I've never had a problem using any smart BSTR wrapper (and I've used many over the years). As long as you use them correctly and are aware of how they behave, any implementation will work just fine, especially in the OP's simple example.

In most cases BSTR indeed carries a null terminated string and nothing is going to be wrong if you cast between BSTR and wchar_t* without using Automation API.
However, these string types are frequently participating in marshaling, which means that there is an agreement about memory allocator behind such strings, and then the whole string is rather a memory block allocated with given allocator, which is typically interpreted as string.
When you use SysString* API then COM subsystem can use the same API to correctly identify the size of the memory block and marshal your call accurately, delivering the string argument exactly as it is somewhere else (and this "elsewhere" can be different thread, process and even remote system). The accuracy of argument passing would be lost if you cast wchar_t* to BSTR, and you don't use the APIs intended for BSTR type. However if there is no marshaling involved, then rather often there is no difference.
All in all you should use BSTR related API and allocations to stay on the safe side of things and not guess if this is actually required in this context or not. You have also good helpers for this, such as bstr_t and wil::unique_bstr and other.

See AllocSysString

"However if there is no marshaling involved, then rather often there is no difference." - That is entirely inaccurate. The layout of a BSTR is of vital importance in situations where no marshaling is involved (e.g. when passing ownership, or modifying the contents). This wording is almost criminally negligent. There is never a guarantee that an interface using a BSTR argument will not make use of the BSTR's entire contract.

I mentioned that the safe approach is to use the relevant APIs. However for over 30 years of COM programming I cannot remember any situation where the layout would be important outside of marshaling scenarios. It was actually my point that one would have hard time finding where it becomes a problem, but if you want to make it safe you would still have to stick to Automation APIs.

It is important even without marshalling. If you cast a wchar_t* to BSTR, and pass it to another function, when that other function calls SysStringLen, it will get garbage.
